# Getting prices of crypto coins

Tags: python, flask, client, raspberry-pi, cryptocurrency

I have been working on this Raspberry Pi project for a while. It uses the Poloniex API to get prices of crypto coins and it shows the prices on multiple OLED displays. The displays use different i2c buses; I am switching between them with a multiplexer.

I am trying to keep the code as organized as possible, but I am not used to writing bigger Python projects as I mainly work with C#. I will probably try to split the program into multiple files later and would need hints where to do it.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask_table import Table, Col

import datetime
import subprocess
import time
import smbus
import Adafruit_SSD1306
import Image
import ImageDraw
import ImageFont
import ImageOps 
import json
import collections
from poloniex import Poloniex
import threading
import logging
# logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
polo = Poloniex()

app = Flask(__name__)

smb_bus = 1
multiplexer_address = 0x70

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
@app.route('/index.html')
def get_coins(name=None):
    coin_pair = json.dumps(polo.returnCurrencies())
    unsorted_coins = json.loads(coin_pair)
    sorted_coins = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(unsorted_coins.items()))

    #remove delisted and disabled coins
    for keys in sorted_coins: 
        if (sorted_coins[keys]["delisted"] == 1) or (sorted_coins[keys]["disabled"] == 1):
            sorted_coins.pop(keys, None)

    return render_template('index.html', coin=sorted_coins.keys())

@app.route('/info')
@app.route('/info.html')
def info():
    process0 = scan0_output = subprocess.Popen(['i2cdetect -y 0'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    process0.wait()
    process1 = scan1_output = subprocess.Popen(['i2cdetect -y 1'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    process1.wait()

    return render_template('info.html', scan0=process0.stdout.read(), scan1=process1.stdout.read())

class multiplexer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.bus = smbus.SMBus(smb_bus)

    def change_channel(self, channel):  

        if   (channel==0): action = 0x01
        elif (channel==1): action = 0x02
        elif (channel==2): action = 0x04
        elif (channel==3): action = 0x08
        elif (channel==4): action = 0x10
        elif (channel==5): action = 0x20
        elif (channel==6): action = 0x40
        elif (channel==7): action = 0x80
        else : action = 0x00

        self.bus.write_byte_data(multiplexer_address,0x04,action)  #0x04 is the register for switching channels 

    def scanner(self): 
        display_a = {} 

        multiplexer_channel = 0
        while multiplexer_channel != 8:

            self.change_channel(multiplexer_channel)

            try:
                oled_display.initialize()
                oled_display.clear()
                state = 1
            except Exception:
                state = 0

            display_a.update({multiplexer_channel : state}) 
            multiplexer_channel += 1 

        print display_a
        return display_a   

class oled():
    def initialize(self):
        RST = 24
        global disp
        disp = Adafruit_SSD1306.SSD1306_128_32(rst=RST, i2c_bus=smb_bus)
        global image
        image = Image.new('1', (disp.width, disp.height))
        global draw
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

    def clear(self):
        disp.begin()
        disp.clear()
        disp.display()


    def draw_image(self, price, percentage, change, coin_name):
        font = ImageFont.truetype('visitor1.ttf', 22)
        font1 = ImageFont.truetype('visitor1.ttf', 19)

        #Display positioning
        line_positionX = 11
        coin_positionX = line_positionX + 4
        percentageSizeX = font1.getsize(percentage)[0]

        percentagePositionX = disp.width - percentageSizeX

        draw.rectangle((0, 0, disp.width, disp.height), outline=0, fill=0)
        # im = Image.open("template.png")
        # image.paste(im)    
        draw.line((line_positionX, 16, 135, 16), fill=255) #vertical
        draw.line((line_positionX, 0, line_positionX, 35), fill=255) #horizontal

        #draw coin price
        change_x_size = font1.getsize(change)[0]

        #if screen cant draw both CoinChange and CoinChangePercentage show only percentage
        if (change_x_size + percentagePositionX < disp.width - coin_positionX):
            draw.text((coin_positionX , 18), change, font=font1, fill=255) 

        draw.text((coin_positionX, -3), price, font=font, fill=255)  
        draw.text((percentagePositionX, 18), percentage, font=font1, fill=255) 
        # draw.text((18, 18), change, font=font1, fill=255) 

        #draw coin name
        coin_name = coin_name[-3:]

        draw.text((0, -3), coin_name[0], font=font1, fill=255) 
        draw.text((0, 8), coin_name[1], font=font1, fill=255) 
        draw.text((0, 19), coin_name[2], font=font1, fill=255) 

        # Display image.
        disp.image(image)
        disp.display()

    # def initialize(self):
    def exit_screen(self):
        font1 = ImageFont.truetype('visitor1.ttf', 30)
        self.clear()
        time.sleep(2)

        for multiplexer_channel, state in available_displays.items():
            if state == 1: #if display is enabled/working
                act.change_output(multiplexer_channel)
                draw.rectangle([(0,0),(128,32)], fill=0)
                draw.text((0 , 0), "DIED", font=font1, fill=255) 
                disp.image(image)
                disp.display()        

class price():

    def coin(self, pair):
        coin_pair = json.dumps(polo.returnTicker()[pair])
        ticker_json = json.loads(coin_pair)

        if pair == "USDT_BTC":
            priceM.formatDataBTC_USD(ticker_json['last'], ticker_json['percentChange'], ticker_json['low24hr'], pair)

        else:
            priceM.formatData(ticker_json['last'], ticker_json['percentChange'], ticker_json['low24hr'], pair)

    def formatData(self, price, percentage, change, pair):

        change = int((float(price) - float(change)) * 100000000)
        change = str(change)
        percentage = float(percentage)* 100
        percentage = round(percentage, 2)

        percentage = str(percentage) + "%"

        #remove the first 0 from the price
        price = price[1:10]

        oled_display.draw_image(price, percentage, change, pair)     

    def formatDataBTC_USD(self, price, percentage, change, pair):
        change = str(int(float(change) - float(price)))
        price = price[0:7] + "$"
        percentage = str(round(float(percentage)* 100, 2))  + "%"

        oled_display.draw_image(price, percentage, change, pair)

class coin():
    def poloCoins():
        coin_pair = json.dumps(polo.returnCurrencies()[0])
        return render_template('index.html', coin_pair=coin)


class activate_job():

    def change_output(self, channel): 
        multiplex.change_channel(channel)

    def initialize_display(self, channel):
        multiplex.change_channel(channel)
        oled_display.initialize()
        oled_display.clear()

    def ticker_display(self ,coin_pair, channel):
        multiplex.change_channel(channel)
        global priceM
        priceM = price()
        # BTC_DGB
        # USDT_BTC
        priceM.coin(coin_pair)
        print "updated price on display: " + str(channel)
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    oled_display = oled()
    act =  activate_job()
    multiplex = multiplexer()
    displays_for_coins = {3:"BTC_DGB", 6:"BTC_SC"}
    available_displays = multiplex.scanner()
    for multiplexer_channel, state in available_displays.items():
        if state == 1: #if display is enabled/working
            act.change_output(multiplexer_channel)
            act.initialize_display(multiplexer_channel)
    while True:
        for display, coin  in displays_for_coins.items():
            try:
                act.ticker_display(coin, display)

            except:      

                oled_display.exit_screen()
                break
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I shall start from the top.

According to the style guide, PEP 8 [imports should be in the following order](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports):

1. > standard library imports
2. > related third party imports local
3. > application/library specific imports

Plus, add a single blank line to separate each group.

So, something like the following:

```
import subprocess
import threading
import logging
import collections
import json
import time
import datetime

from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask_table import Table, Col

from poloniex import Poloniex
import smbus
import Adafruit_SSD1306
import Image
import ImageDraw
import ImageFont
import ImageOps
```

A small thing to note is that the convention for class names -as defined in the aforementioned PEP 8- is that they are `CamelCase`.

I definitely recommend somehow splitting up your code. You could put it into a package along the lines of the following:

```
.
my_script.py
my_package
|   +-- __init__.py
|   +-- multiplexer.py
|   +-- display.py
|   +-- currency.py
```

Your multiplexer class and everything to do with it could go into `multiplexer.py`. `oled()` into `display.py` and the `price` and `coin` class could go into `currency.py` -which I am sure could have a better name .... You might even be able to get by with just putting `multiplexer.py`, `display.py`, and `currency.py` in with `myscript.py` instead of in a separate package.